# Having trouble showing up the highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to use highcharts for the first time.. i want to use the library locally, so i donloaded the entire package.. and placed the two files 'jquery.1.9.1.min.js' and 'hghcharts.js' in the same directory as my html file nad tried to run the following script.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='highcharts.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.1.9.1.min.js'></script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</head>

<body>
<script>
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Temperature (°C)'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: '°C'
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Tokyo',
                data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
            }, {
                name: 'New York',
                data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
            }, {
                name: 'Berlin',
                data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
            }, {
                name: 'London',
                data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
            }]
        });
    });


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Nothing shows up, i know i'mmessing up with the directories or dont know what js files to include or where to place my html file.. kindly help, i want to run it all in offline mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load jquery before you load highcharts.

Switch:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='highcharts.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.1.9.1.min.js'></script>
```

to:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.1.9.1.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='highcharts.js'></script>
```